# Trimming the fat from an HTML button created using div

Tags: html, css

I have a link which I want to appear as a button. Below is the code for it where I wrapped the href in a div. Problem is the button appears too "fat". How can I make the red around the text less?

I tried reducing the width of the div but that just makes the text to wrap.

```html
<div style="width: 100px;background-color:#cc0000; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;padding: 10px; padding-bottom: 20px">
     <a href="" class="font-regular" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Arial Regular', Arial; color: white; text-decoration: none; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px;padding: 6px 18px;">
                                    Just do it!
     </a>
 </div>
```

**UPDATE**

What I am asking is the ratio of text to background color red should be similar to the button shown in this screenshot http://grab.by/RdFa.

Comment: Could you show us a live example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now its ok, just adjust the padding  and width.

```html
<div style="width: 80px;background-color:#cc0000; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;padding: 5px;">
     <a href="" class="font-regular" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Arial Regular', Arial; color: white; text-decoration: none; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px;padding: 6px;">
                                    Just do it!
     </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make padding bottom:10px as well.

```html
<div style="width: 100px;background-color:#cc0000; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;padding: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px">
     <a href="" class="font-regular" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Arial Regular', Arial; color: white; text-decoration: none; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px;padding: 6px 18px;">
                                    Just do it!
     </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that still doesn't get it exactly as I want it.

Comment: @AbuMariam how exactly do you want it ? Maybe share a picture. Fat button is not really a good description :)